# How to add custom wizards in TYPO3 9 TCA?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

Related to [How to add custom wizards in typo3 7 TCA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38099950/how-to-add-custom-wizards-in-typo3-7-tca) how can costum wizards in TYPO3 9 be implemented? I've added my entry to the Routes.php

```
return [
    'tx_csseo_preview' => [
        'path' => '/wizard/tx_csseo/preview',
        'target' => \Clickstorm\CsSeo\UserFunc\PreviewWizard::class . '::render'
    ],
    'tx_csseo_permalink' => [
        'path' => '/wizard/tx_csseo/permalink',
        'target' => \Clickstorm\CsSeo\UserFunc\PermalinkWizard::class . '::render'
    ]
];
```

How can I add them now to my TCA field?

```
'tx_csseo_title' => [
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:cs_seo/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:pages.tx_csseo_title',
        'exclude' => 1,
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'input',
            'max' => $extConf['maxTitle'],
            'eval' => 'trim',
            'fieldWizard' => [
                'tx_csseo_preview' => [
                    'disabled' => false,
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
```

This does not work. What do I miss? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related to your kind of wizard the registration-process is different and extensive explained [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/FormEngine/Rendering/Index.html#add-fieldcontrol-example). You can leave the entries in Routes.php away (perhaps even the whole file if nothing else is inside).

Registration is done in `ext_localconf.php`:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['formEngine']['nodeRegistry'][1485351217] = [
   'nodeName' => 'importDataControl',
   'priority' => 30,
   'class' => \T3G\Something\FormEngine\FieldControl\ImportDataControl::class
];
```

Then reference the new wizard in TCA:

```
'somefield' => [
   'label'   => $langFile . ':pages.somefield',
   'config'  => [
      'type' => 'input',
      'eval' => 'int, unique',
      'fieldControl' => [
         'importControl' => [
            'renderType' => 'importDataControl'
         ]
      ]
   ]
],
```

Then finally the class with the "magic"

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace T3G\Something\FormEngine\FieldControl;

use TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Form\AbstractNode;

class ImportDataControl extends AbstractNode
{
   public function render()
   {
      $result = [
         'iconIdentifier' => 'import-data',
         'title' => $GLOBALS['LANG']->sL('LLL:EXT:something/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:pages.importData'),
         'linkAttributes' => [
            'class' => 'importData ',
            'data-id' => $this->data['databaseRow']['somefield']
         ],
         'requireJsModules' => ['TYPO3/CMS/Something/ImportData'],
      ];
      return $result;
   }
}
```

In the linked example there is still an Ajax Route with corresponding files, including a special defined route, but that's not required to get the basic wizard shown.

Concerning the registration in `ext_localconf.php` there is above the number `1485351217` as array-key shown. For an own registered node just calculate once the current time as unix-timestamp and enter that instead. So it's unique and can't be mistaken with other definitions of any registered nodes.

In contrast to the linked example I used slightly different descriptions, so I call the process in ext_localconf.php `registering`, and the inclusion in TCA `referencing`. Perhaps this small difference makes it a bit more clear.

**Icons**

Concerning Icons there is still a difference to earlier TYPO3 versions, they have to be registered now too and in TCA they are only referenced too by the registered name. Here in the TCA-file is no icon referenced but the class below makes usage of it. Here is an example how an icon has to be registered in ext_tables.php:

```
$systemIconRegistry = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconRegistry::class);
$systemIconRegistry->registerIcon(
    'imagemapwizard_link_edit',
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconProvider\BitmapIconProvider::class,
    [
        'source' => 'EXT:imagemap_wizard/Resources/Public/Icons/link_edit.png'
    ]
);
```

The new icon registry is implemented starting with TYPO3 version 7.5

Answer (score -2):

Don't forget the configuration in  *YourExtension/Configuration/Backend/AjaxRoutes.php*. See the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/FormEngine/Rendering/Index.html)